# Flutter: How to draw a realtime line chart?

Tags: flutter

I would like to draw a real time line chart in the flutter application.
- use a timer to get a real time data every 5ms.
- draw a line chart to display the trend.

I am still new to the flutter development. I looked at CustomPainter/Canvas solution.  I needs to draw the entire line whenever I get the data (every 5 ms).  Is there a way I only draw partial area?

Thanks.